# XFCE 22.0.4 won't wake up after hibernation

Tags: 22.04, xfce, hibernate, lock-screen

XFCE 22.0.4 won't wake up after hibernation, I did all the hardware stress tests and everything is fine with the hardware, but at the system level there is probably a problem, when I logout then and after a certain time, I can't log in, it just gives black screen and only after reboot everything is fine.

Comment: Try https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate

Comment: Xubuntu ISOs offer two kernel stacks, with the default selected by what you install; one option maybe to try the other software stack. What media did you install on, and have you explored that?  (ie. 22.04 media exist(ed) with 5.15, 5.19, 6.2 & now 6.5 kernels allowing you to test *live*; ie. without changing your installed system).  It's something I'd consider tresting; plus multiple stacks can co-exist unless you're using specific closed-source kernel modules but you gave few specifics.